# Writing to a CSV without pandas

Tags: python, csv, rows

I am writing a list of numbers to a CSV.

However it is putting each number into a different cell.

I can not figure out why.

#### What I tried

I was using `csv.writerow()` which puts them all into the same row.
But I need them in columns.

Attempting to fix that I switched to `csv.writerows()` which puts them columns, but every single number is in a new row separated from the next.

Does anyone know why this is?

#### Code

```py
class readingJ1Average:
    def readingJ1(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j1 = f.readlines()[46:47]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j1_join = ('\n'.join(j1))
            #Pulling only average
            j1_value = j1_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j1_list.append(j1_value)


    def readingJ2(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j2 = f.readlines()[47:48]
            print(j2)
            #Coverting list to a string
            j2_join = ('\n'.join(j2))
            #Pulling only average
            j2_value = j2_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j2_list.append(j2_value)

    def readingJ3(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j3 = f.readlines()[48:49]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j3_join = ('\n'.join(j3))
            #Pulling only average
            j3_value = j3_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j3_list.append(j3_value)

    def readingJ4(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j4 = f.readlines()[48:49]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j4_join = ('\n'.join(j4))
            #Pulling only average
            j4_value = j4_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j4_list.append(j4_value)

    def readingJ5(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j5 = f.readlines()[49:50]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j5_join = ('\n'.join(j5))
            #Pulling only average
            j5_value = j5_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j5_list.append(j5_value)

    def readingJ6(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j6 = f.readlines()[50:51]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j6_join = ('\n'.join(j6))
            #Pulling only average
            j6_value = j6_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j6_list.append(j6_value)

    def readingJ7(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            j7 = f.readlines()[51:52]
            #Coverting list to a string
            j7_join = ('\n'.join(j7))
            #Pulling only average
            j7_value = j7_join[5:16]
            #Appending to a list
            j7_list.append(j7_value)

#Beginning main code
j1_list = []
j2_list = []
j3_list = []
j4_list = []
j5_list = []
j6_list = []
j7_list = []

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ1(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ2(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ3(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ4(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ5(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ6(filepath)

for file in os.listdir():
#check if file is in text format or not
if file.endswith(".ls"):
    filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
    #calling the read function
    readingJ1Average.readingJ7(filepath)

with open('C:/Users/DunningJ3/Desktop/sample.csv', 'w') as wf:
write = csv.writer(wf)
write.writerows(j1_list)
#TXT file to Excel
```

Comment: So after further research and writing the CSV to a .txt file I see it is putting commas between every single number and white space in the list. I believe there is a way to fix it using a delimiter (i think) but do not know the syntax of it.

Comment: This would be easier as a [mcve], with the used `import` statements, less duplicated code, and inputs and expected vs actual outputs.

Comment: writerows() is expecting an iterable of iterables (such as a list of lists).  Each inner iterable will become a single row, where each element of the iterable will be single cell.
Example, if I have [["A", "B", "C"], [1, 2, 3]], and pass that to writerows(), it will give me a csv with 2 rows with 3 columns in each row.  First row is "A,B,C" and second row is "1,2,3".

Comment: So i need to store my current list into another one?

Comment: Please add a small worked sample to your question showing the format of the CSV files and what your expected output would be for it. Your script could then be tested with it and we could then help provide a much simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

The fast answer is that you need to convert the row to string instead on keeping it as a list or to use a matrix. But first you need to keep things simple, cleaning all code smells and following best practices, otherwise will be hard to figure out a solution.

The csv.writerows() is expecting a list of rows but you want to transpose them, so we can solve this by using a matrix or an array of string. For both the new item (a list of numbers or a string) is generated per row of the original csv taking the same position.

Let's say the original csv is "A" and contains items in the form of "a(ij)". You will build a new "A' " where it's items are "a'(ji)" and csv.writerows() is expecting:

```
[ 
  [a'(00), a'(01), ..., a'(0i)]
  [a'(10), a'(11), ..., a'(1i)]
  ...
  [a'(j0), a'(j1), ..., a'(ji)
]
```

This is kind transposing a matrix btw

```
import csv

matrix = []

def init_matrix(total_lines):
    for i in range(total_lines):
        matrix.append([])

def readAll(filepath, csv_separator):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        total_rows = len(lines)
        total_cols = len(lines[0].split(csv_separator))
        print('Total Rows ', total_rows)
        print('Total Cols ', total_cols)
        init_matrix(total_cols)
        for j in range(total_rows):
            line = lines[j].rstrip()
            elements = line.split(csv_separator)
            for i in range(total_cols):
                matrix[i].append(elements[i])


def main():
    filepath = f"{'test.csv'}"
    readAll(filepath, ',')
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as wf:
        write = csv.writer(wf)
        write.writerows(matrix)

main()
```

And here the sample test.csv file

```
a,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
b,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
d,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
e,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
f,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
g,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
```

The output will be

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6
7,7,7,7,7,7,7
8,8,8,8,8,8,8
9,9,9,9,9,9,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```